# Azure - Changed admin password for DB and now can't access database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a Azure account and have deployed an MVC app.

I changed the admin password for the db and updated my web.config accordingly and after I've published the app, the app can't access the db.  I get the following error:

```
Login failed for user 'xxx'.
This session has been assigned a tracing ID of '11a7a162-ff21-42f0-a8ea-8e5ce25b8ab6'.  
Provide this tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance.
```

Any help appreciated.  I've been over everything with a fine toothcomb and I can login to the db using SQL Management studio using the new credentials.  The DB is dead however.

The only other thing I did was change the size of the DB from 1GB to 5GB.

Comment: Is it just your application can't access the DB? are you able to connect to it via the management portal / silverlight app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix this and for anyone out there, here's the gotcha.  Even when I changed the connection strings in the publish profile, they were ignored.  I had to go to the Azure portal and change the connection string settings against the deployed web app directly.

I wonder whether this is a bug with Azure.  I would have expected my publish profile settings to change the connection strings on the deployed application.